# Delta lake write optimization

Tags: amazon-s3, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, delta-lake

I am writing data to Delta lake which is partitioned. dataset is around 10GB. Currently it is taking 30 minutes to write to s3 bucket.
`df.write.partitionBy("dated").format("delta").mode("append").save("bucket_EU/temp")`

How can i better optimize this? is there any way to reduce the time?

Answer (score 0):

- You can try to increase the instance type or number workers node if possible .
- `ThreadPoolExecutor` for runs each of your workers in separate threads within the main process. You can find a sample code here .

Code snippet :

```
def writeS3(curr_date):
    print(f"Starting S3 write for date - {curr_date}")
    data_df1 = data_df.withColumn("date1", f.from_unixtime(f.unix_timestamp(data_df.LD_TS), "yyyy-MM-dd"))
    display(data_df1)
    print(curr_date)
    save_df = data_df1.filter(f"date1='{curr_date}'").drop('date1')
    save_df.write.parquet(f"s3://location")

jobs = []
results_done = []

total_days = 30

with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=total_days+1) as e:
  print(f"{raw_bucket}/{db}/{table}/")
  for curr_date in date_range:
      print(f"Starting S3 write for date - {curr_date}")
      jobs.append(e.submit(writeS3, curr_date))
#       result_done = job.result()
#       print(f"Job Completed - {result_done}")
print("Task complete")
```